# Translation request in imparfait

Tags: traduction, imparfait

Can you help me translate this in imparfait please?

> I was energetic, silly, a little angel, a very smart kid.

Comment: Sorry, but without some kind of context, what your level of French is and what you're trying to say more specifically and who you're saying it to, it's hard to do a good job giving a random translation and explanation that might not suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

J'étais energétique, naïf, un petit ange, un gamin très intelligent.

Remember the imperfect tense endings:

je/tu          -ais,
ils/elles/on   -ait,
nous           -ions,
vous           -iez,
ils/elles      -aient,

Comment: "Silly" is not "naïf" (naive) but "bête".

Comment: Then just say "idiot", depends on context so technically it does mean it too.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get your idea; I see from a dictionary that you have 3 senses: foolish, ridiculous, not practical or serious; what elicits "naive" from the context, the fact that the kid is smart?

Comment: Indeed, in context I don't think *bête* works the best here, but it's impossible to know without a precision of the meaning of *silly* meant. It could be lacking knowledge of the world, having juvenile humour, having unsound ideas...

Comment: Exactly as Luke said.